# R, java version error in sparklyr spark_connect

Tags: r, sparklyr

I do not understand this error or how to bypass it, any help would be appreciated.

```
library(sparklyr)
spark_install(version = "3.0.0")
sc <- spark_connect(master = 'local')
```

> Error: Java 11 is only supported for Spark 3.0.0+

The thing is I have Java Version 8 Update 261 and I have updated my environment variables appropriately, so I am unsure of what exactly is going on.

Comment: Does `sparklyr` use java? It isn't listed as an `Import:` ... are you sure it isn't something on the spark side?

Comment: I encounter the same error, but with spark 2.3.  In a terminal I am able to run both pyspark and spark-shell from the spark installation installed with sparklyr's spark_install(version="2.3").